# Media Items in JSQMessageViewController's Collection cells are not showing in IOS 14

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller, ios14

I am using JSQMessageViewController and I am facing the issue (only in ios14) that i cant see media items like Images, Video and Audio in device though these views are generating debug view hierarchy. See below attached image:-

debug view hierarchy screenshot:

[image]

here is the description of UIImage inside collection view cell:
<UIImageView: 0x7fe7d6d95b30; frame = (20 8; 177 131); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001ce4ec0>>

here is the screenshot attached of screen:

[image]

You can see the view has generated space for image, but its not showing up!

Is anyone facing this issue? how can i solve this problem. This issue is occurring in iOS 14, it works perfectly in iOS 13.

Comment: `JSQMessageViewController ` hasn't been updated for more than 4 years and is no longer supported. Maybe you can try `MessageKit` instead: https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to overwrite in **JSQMessagesMediaViewBubbleImageMasker.m**
method **- (void)jsq_maskView:(UIView *)view withImage:(UIImage *)image** and change line:

```
view.layer.mask = imageViewMask.layer;
```

to be

```
view.maskView = imageViewMask;
```

I suggest you to use category for that. For me that was solution.

Comment: Thanks, @Vladimir This solution worked for me but I want to confirm that do we need to add a check for ```#available(iOS 14.0, *)``` before adding this line?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest to change like as follows along with the Vladimir answer for backward compatibility:

```
if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
    view.maskView = imageViewMask;
} else {
    view.layer.mask = imageViewMask.layer;
}
```